# asp.net is not call a method repeatedly

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Asp.net is not call a method repeatedly(method `TableAdapterExtensions.Increment(`)).Method calls of view.This is part of javascript

```
     function SetCountSize() {
    var CountSizes = $('#CountSizes').val();
    if (CountSizes != "") {
        $("[code]").each(function(indx, element) {
            element.remove();
        });
        for(var i=0;i<CountSizes;i++)
        $("#InsertSide").before('@Html.Side(TableAdapterExtensions.Increment())');
    }
}
```

method TableAdapterExtensions.Increment()

```
  public static int Increment()
    {


        int j= (int)cache.Get("increment", null);
        cache.Set("increment", ++j, null, null);
        int h = j;
        return j;
    }
```

Comment: yes,I tried to call from с# code.   @for (int t=0;t<4;t++)
{
  <div>@TableAdapterExtensions.Increment()</div>
}.this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razor code is parsed on the server before its sent to the view. Your `@Html.Side(TableAdapterExtensions.Increment()` helper is called once (the javascript loop does not exist yet) and renders its output. When the view is generated, your script will look like

```
for(var i=0;i<CountSizes;i++)
    $("#InsertSide").before(1); // assuming j=1
}
```

so when the `SetCountSize()` function is called, it will just repeat the same value

Comment: Good call, missed that.

Comment: Not exactly sure what your trying to output (it seems to be just incremeting a number which could be done in javascript/jquery). The other alternative is use ajax inside the loop to call a controller method that returns the value, but this would be inefficient unless you expecting non-sequential values.